# Image border hover won't work

Tags: html, css, image, hover, border

I have an image centered on the screen that I would like a border around, which when hovered over changes color. I am trying to do this as you can see in the code below, but the problem is that the image just keeps being a link but no border, what is wrong?

html code:

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="content">

        <div class="10Img">
            <a href=""><img src="10Pimg.png" alt="10img" style="width:900px; height:200px"></a>
        </div>

    </div>


    </div>
```

css code:

```
#content{
    padding-bottom: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -450px;
    top: 200px;
}

#container{
    height:100%;
}

.10Img{
    border: 2px solid grey;
}

.10Img a:hover{
    outline: 2px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is you are starting your class name with a numerical character change `10Img`  and start it with an alphabetic character.
Ex. i change it from 10Img to `aImg`

Then you can use

```
.aImg  img {
 border: 2px solid grey;
}
```

or only

```
.aImg {
     border: 2px solid grey;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qhhrdk5o/1/)**

```
a img {
    border: 2px solid grey;
}
a img:hover {
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your css class `10Img` doesn't work, because css class names must not begin with a number, see:

[Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-selectors)

So if you call your class `Img10` instead of `10Img` it should work.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <div class="Img10">
            <a href=""><img src="http://dummyimage.com/900x200/000/fff" alt="10img" style="width:900px; height:200px" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also you may want to have the `:hover` border on the `div` instead on the `a`:

```
#content{
    padding-bottom: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -450px;
    top: 200px;
}

#container{
    height:100%;
}

.Img10{
    border: 2px solid grey;
}

.Img10:hover{
    outline: 2px solid black;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/k2Ld7yfe/

Answer (score 0):

See This [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/evhxrrjh/)

```
.Img{border: 2px solid grey;}
.Img a:hover{
outline: 2px solid black;}
```

Note: Class Name can not start with integer.

Refer [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-selectors) for Rules regarding naming.